# Convert automatically a specific color to another inside a set of png icons

Tags: interface-design, png, script, button

I have a set of `.png` images (which are controls like buttons, sliders, checkbox etc for a GUI) and I'd like to convert a specific color to another for each files using an automatic solution.

For example, let's say that my input are theses three files

```
button_small.png
button_medium.png
button_large.png
```

which are yellow buttons with a black stroke.

I'd like my output to be the same (name, paths, sizes) but with the yellow color (or hex value) replaced by orange color (or an other hex value).

Is there any solution, like a script or photoshop tool ?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends a bit on how your buttons actually look like. Are the yellow pixels really one single hex color or is there a range of values caused by anti-aliasing?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Hard to say what might or not be possible without access to the PNG files. Can you share them?

Comment: @Wolff: somes are, other not. but let's say for a single hex color

Comment: @BillyKerr: yes sure, it's controls files from touchgfx designer: https://easyupload.io/kagd3z

Comment: There's some anti-aliasing and shading on the buttons, so perhaps a Hue/Saturation adjustment would work for you. You could record it as an Action and apply to a whole folder of PNGs using File > Automate > Batch.

Comment: @BillyKerr : Interesting, I'll try when I figured out how to in PS! Thanks.